# Why StringCopyFromLiteral is faster than StringCopyFromString?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, copy-constructor, stdstring

The `Quick C++ Benchmarks` example:

```
static void StringCopyFromLiteral(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::string from_literal("hello");
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(from_literal);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(StringCopyFromLiteral);

static void StringCopyFromString(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  std::string x = "hello";
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::string from_string(x);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(StringCopyFromString);
```

http://quick-bench.com/IcZllt_14hTeMaB_sBZ0CQ8x2Ro

What if I understand assembly...

---

More results:

http://quick-bench.com/39fLTvRdpR5zdapKSj2ZzE3asCI

Comment: It looks like the creation case is being optimized by the compiler to precisely populate the string object with constant values not using a loop, while the copy case has no such optimization, and the contents are copied over in a loop. You'd probably see something very different if you randomly generate a string in a `char` array in the first case.

Comment: Note that both cases involve string creation, so the names could instead be "StringCreate" and "StringCreateAndCopy", which gives a hint as to why the latter might be more expensive . . .

Comment: @ruakh In both cases, something is being copied. But in the former the source is a string literal (a `char` array) and in the latter it's a string object. The source is not relevant _except_ that compilers appear to implement an optimization when a string literal is used. I suspect that performance will be pretty much identical if the compiler cannot perform this optimization (the input `char` array in the first case is unknown to the compiler).

Comment: @cdhowie: Sure, but this sort of optimization is standard fare; we don't describe `int i = 3` as "copying" the literal 3, whereas `int j = i` does "copy" the value from `i`. (I'm not saying that this is a bad question -- one could imagine a compiler that failed to optimize the first case, or that optimized the second case to be equivalent to the first case -- but "Why string creation is faster than string copy?" is not a good expression of the question.)

Comment: @ruakh But in _both cases_ a string is being copied from something else. I'm just pointing out that the names StringCreate and StringCreateAndCopy are not really any better. How about StringCopyFromLiteral and StringCopyFromString?

Comment: @cdhowie: Not bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple. In the case where you construct an `std::string` from a small string literal, the compiler optimizes this case by directly populating the contents of the string object using constants in assembly.  This avoids expensive looping as well as tests to see whether small string optimization (SSO) can be applied.  In this case it knows SSO can be applied so the code the compiler generates simply involves writing the string directly into the SSO buffer.

Note this assembly code in the StringCreation case:

```
// Populate SSO buffer (each set of 4 characters is backwards since
// x86 is little-endian)
19.63% movb   $0x6f,0x4(%r15)    // "o"
19.35% movl   $0x6c6c6568,(%r15) // "lleh"
// Set size
20.26% movq   $0x5,0x10(%rsp)    // size = 5
// Probably set heap pointer. 0 (nullptr) = use SSO buffer
20.07% movb   $0x0,0x1d(%rsp)
```

You're looking at the constant values right there. That's not very much code, and no loop is required.  In fact, the `std::string` constructor *doesn't even have to be invoked!*  The compiler is just putting stuff in memory in the same places where the `std::string` constructor would.

If the compiler cannot apply this optimization, the results are quite different -- in particular, if we "hide" the fact that the source is a string literal by first copying the literal into a char array, the results flip:

```
char x[] = "hello";
for (auto _ : state) {
  std::string created_string(x);
  benchmark::DoNotOptimize(created_string);
}
```

Now the "from-char-pointer" case takes [twice as long](http://quick-bench.com/uTNPgA9V7meOAlZn3f88_y4Fr9A)!  Why?

I *suspect* that this is because the "copy from char pointer" case cannot simply check to see how long the string is by looking at a value.  It needs to know whether small string optimization can be performed.  There's a few ways it could go about this:

1. Measure the length of the string first, make an allocation (if needed), then copy the source to the destination.  In the case where SSO does apply (it almost certainly does here) I'd expect this to take twice as long since it has to walk the source twice -- once to measure, once to copy.
2. Copy from the source character-by-character, appending to the new string.  This requires testing on each append operation whether the string is now too long for SSO and needs to be copied into a heap-allocated char array.  If the string is currently in a heap-allocated array, it needs to instead test if the allocation needs to be resized.  This would also take quite a bit longer since there is at least one test for each character in the source string.
3. Copy from the source in chunks to lower the number of tests that need to be performed and to avoid walking the source twice.  This would be faster than the character-by-character approach both because the number of tests would be lower and, because the source is not being walked twice, the CPU memory cache is going to be more effective.  This would only show significant speed improvements for long strings, which we don't have here.  For short strings it would work about the same as the first approach (measure, then copy).

Contrast this to the case when it's copying from another string object: it can simply look at the `size()` of the other string and immediately know whether it can perform SSO, and if it can't perform SSO then it also knows exactly how much memory to allocate for the new string.

Comment: Check this: http://quick-bench.com/39fLTvRdpR5zdapKSj2ZzE3asCI

Comment: While SSO affects some of the difference between the performances of the different types of source data (literal, pointer, string), the same same stepwise performance phenomena appears _without_ SSO as well, when using strings too long to fit in the SSO buffer: http://quick-bench.com/MnBKxqOIAYz6DNRZh3nzM_Pf8Kw